# MapMyIndia react-native library not working

Tags: android, react-native, dictionary

MapMyIndia react-native library not working. While initialising facing issue with **SDK not initialised**.

```
Version Details: 
React Native - 0.72.4
React - 18.2.0
mapmyindia-map-react-native-beta - ^0.4.2
```

[image]

Note: I have tried with valid required keys. But, same issue persist.

Comment: Did you read the installation guides in the wiki?

Comment: @Jankapunkt Yes, I have read and followed the same. https://github.com/mappls-api/mapmyindia-map-react-native-beta